# Windows Contacts in Outlook 2010

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, contacts

How do I make Outlook 2010 use my Windows Contacts?

I don't want to import my Windows Contacts into Outlook 2010, I just want Outlook to use the contacts directly as an addressbook.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Are you still using Vista?  There are no Windows Contacts in Win7.</strike>  They have been replaced with Windows Live Contacts.  You will see them in Outlook when you have installed the [Outlook Connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlook_Connector), which allows you to seemlessly use the Windows Live services, like Calendar, Tasks, Contacts and Hotmail.

Comment: No, I'm using Windows 7, and I'm pretty sure Windows Contacts are alive and well. However, I did consider moving my contacts to Windows Live, maybe that's the best option. But would that work when I'm offline??

Comment: Ah, yes it is still there.  The reason that I thought it had gone was because I stopped using it after Windows Live Messenger 9.0 onwards, as it can no longer sync with Windows Live Messenger/Contacts/Hotmail.

Comment: Yes, they will appear in Outlook offline, through the Connector.

Comment: But thanks for the pointer to the Outlook Connector, I think I'll use it to move my contacts to "the cloud" permanently from now on.